# SQL - to find the longest string from a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

Each time a user searches for something it gets recorded to table.

The sub-searches are also recorded. They are recorded with an asterisk.

I am trying to pull the longest string for each search.

A user can do multiple searches.

Here for example, User1 searches for "data management" and "status information". I want to ignore the partial searches(sub-searches) recorded, like "data manag*", "data managem*", "status in*" and pull the complete search that was done.

table

```
                id user   data
                ---------------
                1  user1  data manag*
                2  user1  confer*
                3  user1  incomplete sear*
                4  user1  data managem*
                5  user1  conference c*
                6  user1  data management
                7  user1  conference call*
                8 user1  status in*
                9 user1  status information
```

Output should be

```
            user1 data management
            user1 conference call*
            user1 incomplete sear*
            user1 status information
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Please explain what is your logic, why user1 has two records?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: sorry, I thought I gave good explanation. A user can do multiple searches. User1 can seached for "data management" and "status information". But the main issue is with the sub-searches appearing in the table. I want to avoid the sub-searches (like "data manag*", "status in*") and obtain only the longest search text.

Comment: Still your logic isnt clear. because you dont said WHY a value is choose over another. Please read the links I provide to teach you how make a better question

Comment: if you ask for `obtain only the longest search text.` why you get two result from `user1`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @JuanCarlosOropeza. I will update the question again.

Comment: That asks for some fuzzy logic. As we see `conference call*` was a main search - there is no `conference calling` or the like without an asterix. So `status in*` could be the sub search for `status information`, and it's very likely at that, but it *could* just as well be a main search on ist own.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user, data
FROM (
        SELECT user,
               data,
               ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION BY user
                                   ORDER BY char_length(data) DESC) rn
        FROM table
     ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks but this is returning only one result per user?

Comment: yes, one result for user. That is what `PARTITION BY user` does. Your sample output return one result for user, isnt?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean one result per user.. I have updated the example. Removing the PARTITION BY user also resulted in one result. Not sure why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Main idea is to order data by `data` column and compare each value with next one. If next value don't starts with current then current value is in desired result.

It is simplified, intermediate query:

```
with
  t(x) as (values
    ('data manag*'),('confer*'),('incomplete sear*'),
    ('data managem*'),('conference c*'),('data management'),
    ('conference call*'),('status in*'),('status information'))
select
  *,
  case
    when right(x,1) != '*' then 1 
    when replace(x,'*','') = substring(y,1,length(replace(x,'*',''))) then 0 
    else 1 
  end hit
from 
  (
    select
      x, lead(x) over (order by x) as y /*lag(x,-1) can be used instead of lead(x)*/
    from t) r;

         x          |         y          | hit 
--------------------+--------------------+------
 confer*            | conference c*      |    0
 conference c*      | conference call*   |    0
 conference call*   | data manag*        |    1
 data manag*        | data managem*      |    0
 data managem*      | data management    |    0
 data management    | incomplete sear*   |    1
 incomplete sear*   | status in*         |    1
 status in*         | status information |    0
 status information |                    |    1
(9 rows)
```

As you can see, desired values is in `x` column where `hit = 1`. Use it as subquery or view to get final result.

Comment: I agree, that's a great idea. You should replace `lag(x,-1)` with `lead(x)` for readability.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It is matter of taste I think. However, you are right, according to documentation. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This would do nicely:

```
with
  searches (id, "user", data) as ( values
    (1, 'user1', 'data manag*'),
    (2, 'user1', 'confer*'),
    (3, 'user1', 'incomplete sear*'),
    (4, 'user1', 'data managem*'),
    (5, 'user1', 'conference c*'),
    (6, 'user1', 'data management'),
    (7, 'user1', 'conference call*'),
    (8, 'user1', 'status in*'),
    (9, 'user1', 'status information')
    )
select "user", data
from searches s
where data not like '%*'
   or not exists (
            select 1
            from searches
            where "user" = s."user"
              and id <> s.id
              and data like (left(s.data, -1)||'%')
          )
```

Comment: Straight-forward. But you should add `and right(s.data, 1) = '*'` to your subquery.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's not necessary, since the subquery is testing for the (non) existence of larger matching strings when the string ends in `*` (from the main WHERE clause, if `s.data` doesn't end in `*` then the EXISTS is not evaluated at all)

Comment: No, with the main search `'findx'` and the sub search `'find*'`, you would select both: `'findx'` because it doesn't end on `'*'` and `'find*'` because it's `like 'find%'` (i.e. `like left('findx', -1) || '%'`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I believe the problem is that you're confusing the purpose of the exists subquery. `'findx'` would end up in the result because it is `not like '%*'`, and `'find*'` would be filtered out because there EXISTS a row where data (`'findx'`) is `like (left(s.data, -1)||'%')` (i.e. `'find%'`)

Comment: Oops, correct, I *was* confused. The problem would be with two main searches 'findx' and 'findx*', where you wouldn't find 'findx*'. Sorry about the confusion. But that you need the additional criteria still holds true :-)